# Read relations from data using igraph python

Tags: python, igraph

I have an example.cvc file containing the following values:

```
pos= [180 270 360 450 540 630 720 810]
mean_values= [(270,630), (540,720),(270,810),(450,630),(180,360), (180,540),(450,810),(360,540),(180,720),(630,810),(270,450),(360,720)]
```

The mean values are basically from 2d gaussian mixture model. Based on my understanding labels can represent vertices (8) and mean_values can be called edges (12).

With regards to data: pos basically represented by the blue and yellow circles values while means values correspond to which one is related to which pos. So for example, among 180,360,540 and 720 label values, 180 connected to 360,540, 720 as seen by arrows and represented by following means values: [(180,360), (180,540),(180,720)] and the similar result can be found with other pos,

Any idea of how to get such a result using igraph. I did a couple of searches but did not get any idea. I am new to igraph, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean "closer" on the number scale? Also what do a, b signify?

Comment: yes. They signify the different mean values of a and b obtained from Gaussian Mixture model.

Comment: why would u need graphs then? correct me if I am wrong but you are finding which mixtures of a are most similar to mixtures of b (at least in terms of closeness of means). so why not just use a simple distance matrix

Comment: Our result shows that, there are two clusters and I would like to know through graph in these two clusters which mean values are closer to each clusters. So I think with distance matrix it is not possible.

Comment: Again it’s not clear to me why it needs a graph. You mentioned in example that 640 is close to 630. Why does that insight need a graph. Is it for just visualising purpose?

Comment: The answer below also does this. He computes distances separately and just plots it in networkx

Comment: Is that what you need?

Comment: Not really. I further modified my question with the expected result. Please do have a look at it

Comment: My apologies. It took me time to think and come up with this simplified version of the question. I will make sure in future, Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to compute the closest set of points like this (Note that I took th e liberty of reading the data from a list instead of a file, you can change it accordingly):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([640., 270., 450., 230., 180., 540., 270., 180., 450., 360., 610.,
       360.])
b = np.asarray([810., 630., 810., 760., 360., 720., 450., 540., 630., 720., 810.,
       540.])


closest_mapping = []

for node in a:
    # Subtract node from each element in b
    # and get the absolute value
    dist_list = np.absolute(np.array(b) - node)

    # Find the element in b with the min. absolute value
    min_element = b[np.argmin(dist_list)]

    # Create a tuple of (node, min_element) and add it to list.
    # This will be used to plot a graph later. 
    # Note that the second element is stored as a string.
    closest_mapping.append((node, str(min_element)))
```

The reason why I have stored the second element as string will be cleared when we plot the graph. You can see the points yourself to verify

```
print(closest_mapping)
#[(640.0, '630.0'),
# (270.0, '360.0'),
# (450.0, '450.0'),
# (230.0, '360.0'),
# (180.0, '360.0'),
# (540.0, '540.0'),
# (270.0, '360.0'),
# (180.0, '360.0'),
# (450.0, '450.0'),
# (360.0, '360.0'),
# (610.0, '630.0'),
# (360.0, '360.0')]
```

I don't know how to plot a bipartite graph using igraph, so I will be using [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) for this:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create an empty graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add the edges from the list we created
G.add_edges_from(closest_mapping)

# Create a bipartite layout 
pos = nx.bipartite_layout(G, a)

# Draw the Graph
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=900, node_color='y')
```

[image]

The nodes on the left side are from `A` while the nodes on the right are from `B`.

**If you want to find closest for every pair of nodes**

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

a = np.asarray([640., 270., 450., 230., 180., 540., 270., 180., 450., 360., 610.,
       360.])
b = np.asarray([810., 630., 810., 760., 360., 720., 450., 540., 630., 720., 810.,
       540.])


closest_mapping = []

# Find mapping for A->B
for node in a:
    # Subtract node from each element in b
    # and get the absolute value
    dist_list = np.absolute(np.array(b) - node)

    # Find the element in b with the min. absolute value
    min_element = b[np.argmin(dist_list)]

    # Create a tuple of (node, min_element) and add it to list.
    # This will be used to plot a graph later. 
    # Note that the second element is stored as a string.
    closest_mapping.append((node, str(min_element)))

# Find Mapping for B->A
for node in b:
    # Subtract node from each element in b
    # and get the absolute value
    dist_list = np.absolute(np.array(a) - node)

    # Find the element in b with the min. absolute value
    min_element = a[np.argmin(dist_list)]

    # Create a tuple of (node, min_element) and add it to list.
    # This will be used to plot a graph later. 
    # Note that the first element is stored as a string.
    closest_mapping.append((str(node), min_element))


# Create an empty graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add the edges from the list we created
G.add_edges_from(closest_mapping)

# Create a bipartite layout 
pos = nx.bipartite_layout(G, a)

# Draw the Graph
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=900, node_color='y')
```

[image]

**Note** The reason why nodes from list `B` are stored as strings is that if they are kept as integers/floats and they have the same value in `A` the Graph will not be bipartite (It will not register duplicate nodes even though both are logically different, hence I kept one list of nodes as string).

**UPDATE:**
Based on the updated question, you directly add the nodes and edges using NetworkX like this:

import networkx as nx

```
pos= [180, 270, 360, 450, 540, 630, 720, 810]
mean_values= [(270,630), (540,720), (270,810), (450,630), (180,360),
              (180,540), (450,810), (360,540), (180,720), (630,810),
              (270,450), (360,720)]
 
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(pos)
G.add_edges_from(mean_values)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=500, with_labels=True, node_color='y')
```

[image: Graph]

You can use `nx.DiGraph` for directed edges like this

```
import networkx as nx

pos= [180, 270, 360, 450, 540, 630, 720, 810]
mean_values= [(270,630), (540,720), (270,810), (450,630), (180,360),
              (180,540), (450,810), (360,540), (180,720), (630,810),
              (270,450), (360,720)]
 
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(pos)
G.add_edges_from(mean_values)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=500, with_labels=True, node_color='y')
```

[image: Directed Graph]

**References**:

- [Bipartite Graphs in NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/bipartite.html)
- [Bipartite Layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.bipartite_layout.html)
- [Numpy argmin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html)

Comment: This is not exactly, I am looking for. I further simplified my question with the expected result. Plz do have a look and let me know if you can help.

Comment: thanks for this. I have another follow up related to igraph. Could you please help me with this? The link for the new question is given below.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64292966/igraph-using-python-with-unknown-lablel-and-edges